# Wrapping EntityFrameWork with IDal<T> interface

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, architecture

I want to wrap my `EntityFrameWork` class with `IDal<T>` interface with `CRUD operations` only.

I thought to create BL Data Model corresponding to each Entity

Meaning if I have `TempEntity` I'll create `TempBlObj` and interface `IDal<TempBlObj>`

Are there any guideliness to complete such task?

I had a problem implementing `Save(TempBlObj)`

as saving in entity is done by:

`mDbEntities.SaveChanges();`

and this relays on change that had been done on entity reference.

Any solutions?

**Update**

I'm doing all this in order to mock my `IDal<T>` interface

For example in order to change TempEntity.status

I'll have to create a concrete method `ChangeStatus()` instead of generic `CRUD` : `Save(BlObj item)`

as save with entity is done like

`..take reference to some entity, do some change..` and

`mMamDbEntities.SaveChanges();`

I tried to add BlObjects in order to loosen dependency between the Bl and concrete EntityFW

**More General:**

When using ORM, what is the best practice for loose cupling, working with `IDal<T>` intreface (`CRUD` operations) ?

Comment: I think you will be fighting the framework!  I think you'll have to specifically detach all other entities to achieve this.  Do you really need it to work this way?

Comment: It's for Unit testing. how would you do it otherwise?

Comment: I am having trouble visualising exactly what you are trying to do, some more context might help.

Comment: While I can see the merit in this for isolating code for unit testing, given that the DAL (i,e, the EntityFramework) is a fairly known quantity, would it not be more pragmatic just to have unit tests that run against the real DAL, and create test DB instances etc in your test setup?

Comment: how would you mock the EntityFW ?

Comment: I wouldn't, I would use it. I am not sure of the value of mocking it.

Comment: wouldn't you wont to save DB calls when you do unit test? as UT should be very very fast

Comment: I guess it depends how big a deal speed is.  If they are tests that will be run daily, overnight its not a big deal.  Also they might not necessarily be that much slower.

Comment: guidelines say UT should run on every build

Comment: Assuming you have some sort of separate CI process set up, this shouldn't really be a major issue.

Comment: Also have a look at http://haacked.com/archive/2005/10/21/10941.aspx.  I suspect this is another grey area in the real world.

Comment: I wrapped with IDal<T>

and used native EF class types

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109192/shouldnt-i-mock-the-entities-of-ef-when-unittesting/13109271#comment17820444_13109271

Answer (score 0):

The responsibility of saving an entity should not be the job of entity itself. It is a bad idea.
You can consider implementing [repository pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) in your situation.

Comment: It's for Unit testing. how would you do it otherwise?

Comment: I had a problem implementing Save(TempBlObj)

as saving in entity is done by:

mDbEntities.SaveChanges();

and this relays on change that had been done on entity reference.

Comment: "The responsibility of saving an entity should not be the job of entity itself." - it can. Such pattern is either "ActiveRecord" or "Row Gateway"

Answer (score 0):

There are several facts I try to keep in mind when planning a repository for my system:

- O/RM is something that helps me to implement storage-unaware entities. That means that I *do not divide* business entities and DB entities specifically. I have a `User` entity - and ORM should persist it no matter how, and I'm not going to introduce additional layers here.
- I'd start with less restrictive interface:

```
     
    interface IDal {
        T Get<T>(id);
        void Save(object o); //or T, if needed
        IQueryable<T> Query<T>();
    }
```

- And - it could be mocked pretty fine (sample using Moq).

```
     
    var users = new List<User>(){ /* Users here */}
    var mockedRepository = new Mock<IRepository>();

    //getup GET
    mockedRepository.Setup(
        self => self.Get<User>( It.IsAny<int>() )
    .Returns( (int id) => _users.First(u => u.Id == id) );
```

Comment: but for EF, T is a concrete DBEntity item. no?

Comment: so how does context.SaveChanges() will work? It relays on changes detection on EF DTOs, no?