# Should I mock the entities of EF when unit testing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, entity-framework-4, rhino-mocks

I read [this post about mocking Entity Framework(EF)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/447988/How-to-Mock-Test-an-Entity-Framework-Model-First-P).

Shouldn't we abstract the entities' types as well? In order to preserve decoupling between the Data Access Layer (DAL) and the Business Layer (BL)?

In the above post, he used EF concrete generated entities types:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetCustomer()
{
    ContextContainerMock container = new ContextContainerMock();
    IMyEntities en = container.Current;

**Customer c = new Customer { ID = 1, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" };**
    en.Customers.AddObject(c);

    CustomerService service = new CustomerService(container);
    var a = service.GetCustomer(1);

    Assert.AreEqual(c.FirstName, a.FirstName);
    Assert.AreEqual(c.LastName, a.LastName);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I don't mock these. I create, test and cleanup directly. This has helped me catch problem that are more real world scenarios when dealing with the database. Mocking is fantastic for testing integrations where you may not have access to a resource like a DB. If this is your case, then you may have no choice. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm want to mock for unit-testing. If I abstract the entity types, how would I implement `entities.SaveChanges()` ?

Comment: As I said, I don't mock these for unit testing. I don't think the value in mocking it will provide a positive return. Unit test against a real instance of a database instead of mocking it. If you absolutely wanted to mock save changes you need to simulate persisting the data. You could use an in memory database for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

The entities, if done correctly, don't depend on any other code, except other entities and value objects (such as string, int, or your own value object). Therefore, there's no need to mock them.

Also, the entities are part of the core of your system. They are what your system is all about. You'd typically want to test what the system behaves like when operating on these classes rather than testing when the system behaves like when operating on *what the tests say* they behave like.

(As a side note, your entities ought to look like and behave like something that exists in the real world. That is, you should be able to reason about the behavior with a non-technical person from the business side of the organisation. From your example I see that it is possible to create a Customer without a name. Is that ok from a business point of view? If not, I'd say you should have the constructor take the first and last name as argument.)

Comment: But then the `BL` and `DAL` will be strongliy coupled to EF specific technology

Comment: EF is your DAL, so that's ok. The BL shouldn't know anything about EF though. IMyEntities belongs to BL and is EF free while MyEntities belongs to DAL and contains EF code.

Comment: I'm missing something. What will be returned from the DAL method `public Clients GetAllClients()`. Isn't `Clients` EF type? so the `BL` will have to know it?

Comment: `Clients` is an entity and it belongs to BL. However, the DAL/EF is responsible for persisting `Clients`. So EF has knowledge about `Clients`, but that doesn't mean that it owns it or that it is EF's type. The UI probably also knows about `Clients` as well, but it doesn't belong to the UI either.

Comment: I meant there is unwanted coupling. `EFEntity.Client` passes through all the application tiers. If we change the DAL technology from EF to Nhibernate - we will have to compile the BL as well and change all the unit-test accordingliy (because theu, as well relay on EF generated types)\

Comment: I think I understand now... You let EF generate your entities (EF Database First approach). This makes you think that EF "owns" the entities. And perhaps you even let EF own them. My recommendation is to use the [EF Code First](http://codefirst.codeplex.com/) approach instead. Hand-craft your entities. Give them all your love. And let EF be an an implementation detail (that can easily be replaced with e.g. NHibernate).

Comment: thanks. So, if I got lagcy code which used EF with DB-First - then I have to couple the application with EF-Entities generated types?

Comment: I guess so. But I don't know database first well enough to help you much with that.